# Can I use mapply function in R with a starting value?

Tags: r, time-series, apply, lapply, mapply

I like to know if it is possible to use the mapply function in R with a starting value. I know how to do it with a for loop (see example below) but since my data is quite large I like to use mapply to speed up the calculation time.
Is it somehow possible to use a pre-condition value for the first iteration?

This is the example that I like to run with mapply:

```
start_value=4 
df=data.frame(A=1:10,B=2:11, C=NA)

for(i in seq_along(df[,1])){
if (i==1){
  df[i,"C"]=start_value- df[i,"A"]+df[i,"B"]
}else{
  df[i,"C"]=df[i-1,"C"]- df[i,"A"]+df[i,"B"]
}
}
```

Comment: `mapply` usually isn't much use when each row depends on the previous one. For your toy example, you could vectorize with `df$C <- start_value + cumsum(df$B - df$A)` (which should be a lot quicker) but not sure how well that would translate to your real use case

Comment: I think lead/lag functions might be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 different versions of the posted `for` loop.

1. `f1`: Remove the condition from the loop;
2. `f2`: precompute the differences `B - A`;
3. `f3`: precompute the differences `B - A`, lagged them with `start_value` as 1st element and `cumsum`.

The 3rd function, `f3`, is 6 times faster than the original.

```
f0 <- function(df, start_value){
  for(i in seq_along(df[,1])){
    if (i==1){
      df[i,"C"]=start_value- df[i,"A"]+df[i,"B"]
    }else{
      df[i,"C"]=df[i-1,"C"]- df[i,"A"]+df[i,"B"]
    }
  }
  df
}
f1 <- function(df, start_value){
  df[1, "C"] <- start_value - df[1, "A"] + df[1, "B"]
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))[-1]){
    df[i, "C"] <- df[i - 1, "C"] - df[i, "A"] + df[i, "B"]
  }
  df
}
f2 <- function(df, start_value){
  tmp <- as.vector(as.matrix(df[c("A", "B")]) %*% c(-1, 1))
  df[1, "C"] <- start_value + tmp[1]
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))[-1]){
    df[i, "C"] <- df[i - 1, "C"] + tmp[i]
  }
  df
}
f3 <- function(df, start_value){
  tmp <- as.vector(as.matrix(df[c("A", "B")]) %*% c(-1, 1))
  y <- c(start_value + tmp[1], tmp[-1])
  df[["C"]] <- cumsum(y)
  df
}


start_value <- 4 
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=NA)

x0 <- f0(df, 4)
x1 <- f1(df, 4)
x2 <- f2(df, 4)
x3 <- f3(df, 4)
identical(x0, x1)  # TRUE
identical(x0, x2)  # TRUE
identical(x0, x3)  # TRUE

library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  f0 = f0(df, 4),
  f1 = f1(df, 4),
  f2 = f2(df, 4),
  f3 = f3(df, 4)
)
print(mb, order = "median")
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#   f3  223.560  234.1325  456.6144  253.780  299.273 19289.107   100 a  
#   f2  962.414 1372.4640 1417.5630 1394.816 1457.883  1899.316   100  b 
#   f1 1561.998 1916.0750 1962.7880 1938.282 1980.583  2379.496   100   c
#   f0 1229.716 1932.5730 1969.8554 1957.974 1992.095  3161.792   100   c
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to change my functiontions according to you suggestion!!!